# Disable NSTextField without changing color of multi-colored text

Tags: objective-c, nstextfield, disabled-control, text-coloring

Whenever I disable an NSTextField the text loses its color and changes to gray. How can I disable the text field and keep the text color? In my particular situation some words are colored red. I'd like those words to stay red when I disable.

Comment: So you are using an attributed string, rather than a plain string?

Comment: Thanks Droppy. I would describe the text as being "dynamically colored" while I type. I catch the `controlTextDidChange` event and color a word red if it's "incorrect". At some point I'm done entering text, and that text box should not be revisited. Therefore I want to disable it, but it should still be visible with my dynamic coloring so I can look back and see which words I got "wrong".

Comment: You should reconsider setting different style for a disabled textfield as it would be confusing to users.

Answer (score 4):

You need to subclass `NSTextField` to do that.  See this [CocoaBuilder thread](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/120068-how-to-disable-gray-an-nstextfield-used-as-static-text.html):

```
- (void)setEnabled:(BOOL)flag
{
    [super setEnabled:flag];

    if (!flag) {
        [self setTextColor:[NSColor secondarySelectedControlColor]];
    } else {
        [self setTextColor:[NSColor controlTextColor]];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I think I need to rephrase my question to be more precise to my situation though. My text is multiple colors... some words are red, for example, and I'd like them and only them to stay red when I disable.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that while I was editing the text I could set colors and everything, but the problem of the text losing color was happening even when I didn't disable the text box. I had neglected to allow my NSTextField to allow rich text. Now the textfield keeps all colors even when I `setEditable:NO`.